# HikariCP not using settings from Spring Boot's application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.3 and I added the following settings for HikariCP in the **application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSize=250
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cachePrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useServerPrepStmts=true

spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=7
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=Test-1
```

But once I start Spring Boot, the values of pool-name and minimum-idle are different :

```
[DEBUG]  HikariConfig - jdbcUrl........................."jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true"
[DEBUG]  HikariConfig - leakDetectionThreshold..........0
[DEBUG]  HikariConfig - maxLifetime.....................1800000
[DEBUG]  HikariConfig - maximumPoolSize.................10
[DEBUG]  HikariConfig - metricRegistry..................none
[DEBUG]  HikariConfig - metricsTrackerFactory...........none
[DEBUG]  HikariConfig - minimumIdle.....................10
[DEBUG]  HikariConfig - password........................<masked>
[DEBUG]  HikariConfig - poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
```

Comment: I have precisely the same problem. Did you find the answer to your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Did you configure your Bean?:

```
@Configuration
public class HikariCPConfig {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
public HikariConfig hikariConfig() {
    return new HikariConfig();
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig());
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you ! I thought I don't need to specify the HikariConfig bean. However after adding this bean, I had to remove the spring.datasource.url, spring.datasource.username,
spring.datasource.password  from my application.properties and to use spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url, spring.datasource.hikari.username and spring.datasource.password  instead.

Comment: Thats correct make sure you also add the property: datasource.hikari.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: There should be no need for either of the beans shown here. Spring Boot will auto-configure Hikari for you using the settings in application.properties.

Comment: You are absolutely right, @Andy !   I forgot to mention that I have two datasources which causes my problem.  I would be glad if you could check whether my workaround is the best way of handling my issue  :[new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44373186/6595261)

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Somebody please, build this man's statue. Thanks alot.

Comment: Thank you @ian1095
I had the dataSource bean created but did not add @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
hence it was not pulling the Hikari properties from property file in my case.