# How to use HikariCP in Spring Boot with two datasources in conjunction with Flyway

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway, hikaricp

I want to use HikariCP as JDBC connection pool in my Spring boot application. I have two datasources (MySQL database as the primary database and accessing those data through Hibernate and additionally an Oracle database for reading some other data through JDBCTemplate).

I set the MySQL datasource as primary bean:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public DataSourceProperties mySQLDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}


@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public DataSource mySQLDataSource() {
    return mySQLDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("oracle.datasource")
public DataSourceProperties oracleDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean(name = "oracleDatabase")
@ConfigurationProperties("oracle.datasource")
public DataSource oracleDataSource() {
    return oracleDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}

 @Bean
 public JdbcTemplate oracleJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("oracleDatabase") DataSource oracleDb) {
     return new JdbcTemplate(oracleDb);
 }
```

and I put the following configurations in my application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource

spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=7
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=Test-1

spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSize=250
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cachePrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useServerPrepStmts=true
```

Unforuntately, these HikariCP configurations are not being read :

```
 HikariConfig - dataSourceJNDI..................none
 HikariConfig - dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
 HikariConfig - driverClassName................."com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 HikariConfig - healthCheckProperties...........{}
 HikariConfig - healthCheckRegistry.............none
 HikariConfig - idleTimeout.....................600000
 HikariConfig - initializationFailFast..........true
 HikariConfig - initializationFailTimeout.......1
 HikariConfig - isolateInternalQueries..........false
 HikariConfig - jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
 HikariConfig - jdbcUrl........................."jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB"
 HikariConfig - leakDetectionThreshold..........0
 HikariConfig - maxLifetime.....................1800000
 HikariConfig - maximumPoolSize.................10
 HikariConfig - metricRegistry..................none
 HikariConfig - metricsTrackerFactory...........none
 HikariConfig - minimumIdle.....................10
 HikariConfig - password........................<masked>
 HikariConfig - poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
```

Creating the HikariCP beans and deactivating the DataSource autoconfiguration and removing  "spring.datasource" :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class SpringApplication {


@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
public HikariConfig hikariConfig() {
    return new HikariConfig();
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig());
}
```

solves my problem :

```
 HikariConfig - dataSourceJNDI..................none
 HikariConfig - dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>, prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048, cachePrepStmts=true, useServerPrepStmts=true, prepStmtCacheSize=250}
 HikariConfig - driverClassName................."com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 HikariConfig - healthCheckProperties...........{}
 HikariConfig - healthCheckRegistry.............none
 HikariConfig - idleTimeout.....................600000
 HikariConfig - initializationFailFast..........true
 HikariConfig - initializationFailTimeout.......1
 HikariConfig - isolateInternalQueries..........false
 HikariConfig - jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
 HikariConfig - jdbcUrl........................."jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB?autoReconnect=true"
 HikariConfig - leakDetectionThreshold..........0
 HikariConfig - maxLifetime.....................1800000
 HikariConfig - poolName........................"Test-1"
```

But then the Flyway showing some weird warnings which were not shown before and I have to create the database Schema manually before running the Spring application, that is : the create schema does not work anymore.

```
[WARN ] JdbcTemplate - DB: Can't create database 'test'; database exists (SQL State: HY000 - Error Code: 1007)
[WARN ] JdbcTemplate - DB: Unknown table 'testSchema.tenant' (SQL State: 42S02 - Error Code: 1051)
[WARN ] JdbcTemplate - DB: Unknown table 'testSchema.user' (SQL State: 42S02 - Error Code: 1051)
```

My Flyway SQL scripts are plain DDL scripts :

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `testSchema` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `testSchema`.`tenant`;

CREATE TABLE `testSchema`.`tenant` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

I think that disabling the Auto-Datasource configuration is not the best solution since Flyway stops creating the schema and showing warnings.  Is there any other way to solve this ?

Answer (score 28):

Declaring your own `DataSource` will already have implicity disabled Spring Boot's auto-configuration of a data source. In other words this won't be having any effect:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

I think the problem lies in the fact that you aren't binding Hikari-specific configuration to your MySQL `DataSource`. You need to do something like this:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.hikari")
public DataSource mySQLDataSource() {
    return mySQLDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}
```

This will mean that your `mySQLDataSourceProperties` are configured with general-purpose data source configuration. They then create a `HikariDataSource` which is further configured with the Hikari-specific configuration.

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510899/spring-batch-create-two-datasources-and-how-to-customized-to-use-other-propert?

Comment: Great answer and thanks for your work on Spring Boot/REST.  Any chance you could kindly include a link to where this is documented in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 9):

Thank you Andy for your fast and valuable answer ! You set me on the right track. After fiddling around, I found this configuration is working for me :

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource") 
  //@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.hikari") can also be used, no difference
    public DataSourceProperties mySQLDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.hikari")
    public DataSource mySQLDataSource() {
        return mySQLDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
    public HikariConfig hikariConfig() {
        return new HikariConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig());
    }
```

and I had to add these settings in the application.properties:

```
# this is absolutely mandatory otherwise BeanInstantiationException in mySQLDataSource ! 
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING}

spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=${JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING}

spring.datasource.hikari.username=user
spring.datasource.hikari.password=pass
```

Comment: Isn't the way you call `hikariConfig()` and `mySQLDataSourceProperties()` @Bean methods directly broken? I don't think Spring is smart enough to proxy those calls, assume you get an empty not-configured-by-properties instance that way? However, those @Bean methods can take parameters, those are initialized beans. See e.g. https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/javaconfig-methods-inter-dependency.html

Comment: I have to add `url` in my properties, too.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following approach

```
    first.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc-url
    first.datasource.username=username
    first.datasource.password=password
    .
    .
    .
    .
    =================== In Java Configuration File ==================
    
    @Primary
   @Bean(name = "firstDataSource")
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "first.datasource")
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }
    

@Primary
        @Bean(name = "firstEntityManagerFactory")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                @Qualifier("firstDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
            Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
            props.put("spring.jpa.database-platform",  "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect");
    .
    .
    .
    
            return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.first.entity").persistenceUnit("firstDB")
                    .properties(props)
                    .build();
        }

    @Primary
        @Bean(name = "firstTransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager firstTransactionManager(
                @Qualifier("firstEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory firstEntityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(firstEntityManagerFactory);
        }

second.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc-url
second.datasource.username=username
second.datasource.password=password
.
.
.
.
=================== In Java Configuration File ==================

   @Bean(name = "secondDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "second.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("secondDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        props.put("spring.jpa.database-platform",  "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect");
.
.
.

        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.second.entity").persistenceUnit("secondDB")
                .properties(props)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager secondTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("secondEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory secondEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(secondEntityManagerFactory);
    }
```